# How to understand why I have random TLS issue on Heroku?

Tags: ssl, heroku, ss

I have calls to my Heroku app using Ruby `Net::HTTP`

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
```

Sometimes on those calls I have

`SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert internal error`

This random and on every version of Ruby.

If I run an SSL-Labs test on my domains I have different behavior between dynos.
No errors:
[image: no errors]

White errors:
[image: errors]

What can I do? How to better find out what is happening?

PS: I already contacted Heroku support